# Axiom of choice? or other theorems?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying the Axiom of Choice.
But it is so hard for me to apply the exercise.

**The question is:**

Let $A$ be any set with more than one element.
Prove that there exists a bijective function 
$f : A\to A$ such that
$f(x)\neq x\text{ }\forall x \in A$.

I don't feel sure that the question is only for applying axiom of choice.
I learned the Zorn's lemma but I dont feel certain to apply the Zorn's lemma.

Please help me.